How to take a value in a cell by (column and row) and copy it to an open cell?
Sub WherePutMe()
Dim rownum As Integer, colltr As String, tc As Range
rownum = InputBox("Enter a Row Number:")
colltr = InputBox("Enter a Column Letter:")
tc = Range(rownum & colltr)
tc = Selection.offset(2, 2)

End Sub

Debug highlights tc = Range(rownum & Colltr), but I'm not sure what is wrong with it.
thank you

tc is a Range, i.e. an object variable, and object variables need Set. You're missing a Set in the next row as well. But the immediate error is that you've got the address backwards... coltr & rownum.

so, change tc As Range and change Set tc = Range(colltr & rownum)

Honestly, I'd recommend using Application.InputBox and prompting the user to select a range in the first place.

BigBen, I'm very new to this, do you mean that you would do the following:
Dim rownum As Integer, colltr As String, tc As Range
rownum = InputBox("Enter a Row Number:")
colltr = InputBox("Enter a Column Letter:")
Set tc = Range(colltr & rownum)
tc = Selection.Offset(2, 2)

I doubt BigBen means that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox

Actually switching the Colltr & Rownum was the issue.  Thank you so much.

You should still use BigBen's suggestion, it makes for better code and a better experience for the user.
